# NLP and CV Text Processing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns,from chest-Xray report, the columns are "findings", "impression" and "file_Name" with directory information. I have have separate directory of chest-Xray  images that i have to crawl through and get the matching "file_Name" (becuase, there are more image files in the directory, than in my dataframe)from image directory and put in pandas dataframe into new column.

There are more than one image for the same file name, please suggest the code and method to solve it.

DataFrame:
[image: DataFrame Example]

and the image directory will be as below:

home -> files -> f1, f2, f3, f4 ..... f11  [f -> folder]
each folder there are thousand of chest-Xray image file in .jpg format.

Comment: Add some example data-frame, expected output and the code that you have tried for ease of understanding.

Comment: @shivarama23 I have given a example of the file system and data frame example, if helps you to understand. thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If your question is that per each `File_Name` you have multiple _different_ images then I would first change the file name for each to match it. If they're the same image then just use one since the others are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I completely understand your question.  Given a `File_Name` like `/home/.../s1234567.txt`, you want to use that value to get a list of image files and append that list to a new column in your DataFrame?  If so, I recommend writing a function like

```
def get_image_paths_from_file_name(file_name):
    # your logic to find the files here
    return ['path/to/img1.jpg', 'path/to/img2.jpg', ...]
```

then add those lists to your DataFrame with

```
df['image_paths'] = df.File_Name.apply(get_image_paths_from_file_name)
```

(where `df` is your DataFrame).